# apache dav_svn: Download rtf files

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

I have dav_svn installed at Apache, and I have the problem that *.rtf files are not downloaded, but instead displayed in the browser window (which is not OK, because these contents are not human-readable). However, other file types like *.exe files are downloaded correctly.

The mods-available/dav_svn.conf file is completely commented out.

My main configuration file is as follows:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:doc|docx|xls|xlsx|odf|rtf|p12|pfx|ppt|pptx)$">
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443>
        .................

        <Location /svn>
                DAV svn
                SVNParentPath /path/to/repositories/

                # our access control policy
                AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/repositories/access_control

                # try anonymous access first, resort to real
                # authentication if necessary.
                Satisfy Any
                Require valid-user

                # how to authenticate a user
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Subversion repository"
                AuthUserFile /path/to/repositories/.htpasswd
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do to enforce that *.rtf files are downloaded?

Comment: Fix client-side **browser settings**

Comment: That's not a good idea, because the repository should be world-readable in the browser; additionally, browsers like my Android browsers don't support something like that, so I couldn't open the RTF using Word for Android, because I wouldn't download the file.